# Include configmap with non-managed helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was wondering if it is possible to include a configmap with its own values.yml file with a helm chart repository that I am not managing locally. This way, I can uninstall the resource with the name of the chart.

Example:

I am using New Relics Helm chart repository and installing the helm charts using their repo name. I want to include a configmap used for infrastructure settings with the same helm deployment without having to use a kubectl apply to add it independently.

I also want to avoid having to manage the repo locally as I am pinning the version and other values separately from the help upgrade install set triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use Kustomize. Let me show you with an example that I use for my Prometheus installation.

I'm using the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart, but add some more custom resources like a SecretProviderClass.

kustomization.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

helmCharts:
  - name: kube-prometheus-stack
    repo: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
    version: 39.11.0
    releaseName: prometheus
    namespace: prometheus
    valuesFile: values.yaml
    includeCRDs: true

resources:
  - secretproviderclass.yaml
```

I can then build the Kustomize yaml by running `kustomize build . --enable-helm` from within the same folder as where my kustomization.yaml file is.

I use this with my gitops setup, but you can use this standalone as well.

My folder structure would look something like this:

```
.
├── kustomization.yaml
├── secretproviderclass.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only Helm without any 3rd party tools like kustomize there are two solutions:

1. Depend on the configurability of the Chart you are using as described by @Akshay in the other answer
2. Declare the Chart you are looking to add a ConfigMap to as a [dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)

You can manage the Chart dependencies in the `Chart.yaml` file:

```
# Chart.yaml
dependencies:
- name: nginx
  version: "1.2.3"
  repository: "https://example.com/charts"
```

With the dependency in place, you can add your own resource files (e.g., the ConfigMap) to the chart. During Helm install, all dependencies and your custom files will be merged into a single Helm deployment.

```
my-nginx-chart/:
  values.yaml # defines all values including the dependencies
  Chart.yaml # declares the dependencies
  templates/ # custom resources to be added on top of the dependencies
    configmap.yaml # the configmap you want to add
```

To configure values for a dependency, you need to prefix the parameters in your `values.yaml`:

```
my-configmap-value: Hello World
nginx: #<- refers to "nginx" dependency
  image: ...
```